# GetObject usage with email scripting stops working over time

Tags: excel, email, vba

I have a large script in excel 2013 that took me months to write, in short it reads through historical and current data that fills a chart (first part works just fine) which I copy and paste into an email that is sent off to the user it concerns.

Original code source is http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

For the first 6-8 months the scripts worked just fine. What happens now is I get through about 70 loop iterations before the scripts continues to run but the emails are not being sent out, they do not appear in the outbox/sent folder in outlook (there are roughly 150 loop iterations total). I have to stop and restart the script at the place it stops working which is messy.

I'd like to start by confirming that I am indeed calling and closing off the CreateObject function correctly in my code. I'm not totally convinced that when Outlook is called by Excel that it is calling the active session (perhaps an error trap needs to be put in but I'm not sure how to do that). Any help is appreciated.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869289.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
Public Sub SendChartByEmail(PasteAdd As String, ByRef UserEntriesArray() As Range)
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Fname, SelectedRange, Message As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim oRange As Range

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'File path/name of the gif file
Fname = Environ$("temp") & "\User_Chart.gif" 'save the chart to %temp% otherwise problems with email
SelectedRange = Environ$("temp") & "\SelectedRange.gif"

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Table").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Export _
        Filename:=Fname, Filtername:="GIF"

x = UBound(UserEntriesArray, 1) 'paste current month user specific data'
Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("Table").Range("I16")
ActiveCell = UserEntriesArray(x, 0)
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate
ActiveCell = UserEntriesArray(x, 2)
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate
ActiveCell = UserEntriesArray(x, 3)
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate
ActiveCell = UserEntriesArray(x, 4)
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate
ActiveCell = UserEntriesArray(x, 5)
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate
ActiveCell = UserEntriesArray(x, 6)
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate
ActiveCell = UserEntriesArray(x, 7)
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate
ActiveCell = UserEntriesArray(x, 9)
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate
ActiveCell = UserEntriesArray(x, 10)
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate
ActiveCell = UserEntriesArray(x, 11)
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate
ActiveCell = UserEntriesArray(x, 12)
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate
ActiveCell = UserEntriesArray(x, 13)
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate
ActiveCell = UserEntriesArray(x, 14)
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate

Set oRange = Range("I15:U16") 'used to reformat cell group

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = UserEntriesArray(0, 1)
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Report for the Month of " & PasteAdd
    .HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & "Greetings " + UserEntriesArray(0, 0) + ",<br>" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf _
                & "<br>Message to the user here.<br><br>" & vbCrLf _
                & "<img src='User_Chart.gif'><br>" & vbCrLf _
                & RangetoHTML(oRange) & vbCrLf _ 'convert cells to html standard'
                & "<br><br><b>Message to the user here</b>"
    .Attachments.Add Fname ', olByValue, 0'
    .Send   'use .Display for testing .Send for mailing
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:03 AM#)
'Delete the gif file
Kill Fname

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Is `On Error Resume Next` hiding error messages you need to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to open Outlook once if it's not already open. Surely creating and closing Outlook so many times puts a strain on resources.

See below code which will help. Place it before the loop to ensure you have an instance of Outlook open before needing to send mails.

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application

On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If olApp Is Nothing Then Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
```

I use early binding, but you can change to late. Once your loop ends, then you release `olApp` (or whatever you call the variable).

Comment: Just so I understand what you mean. Are you saying that in main I should declare olApp, pass it by reference to the mailer subroutine, then at the end of the sub, reset it to a new outlook item so it never closes? I'm guessing if I were to do that I would need to pass it by reference as well....

Comment: @SomeDude - That would work. You could even just pass the `olMail` Item to the `SendChartByEmail` function. You don't need to create a new outlook item each time if you have to send 150 different emails in one run. Use the same instance for each loop and just create a new mail 150 times.